# Multiple Drag Drop multiple elements into canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag-and-drop, fabricjs

Part of my project is drag and dropping multiple images from a div element into a canvas, the images are of .svg type and im using the library [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com) to render those images. The problem im facing is that the file doesnt get dropped into the canvas more than once.

Alerting at each level shows that the function drop is called only once despite the drag function being called twice.

Here's the part of the javascript code:

```
var object = new Image();

function allowDrop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=document.getElementById(ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text")).getAttribute('src');
    object.src = data.toString();
main();

}
```

main() is the function where the url of images are caught using object.src and then are rendered using fabric.js library